# Why is my cloth animation so buggy?

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

Can someone tell me why my clothanimation is so buggy?

Comment: This is the link to the file: https://pasteall.org/media/9/3/939981b34a1811097470f7f5372f0cad.blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the scale of your cloth and in the *Physics* panel > *Self Collisions* > lower down the *Distance* value, for the moment it's too high which makes the mesh interacts too much with itself, therefore your problem. You can also increase the *Quality Steps* a bit at the top of the panel.

[image]

Comment: Oh yea! that worked. Thank you very much.